# Android: possible to access kernel modules directly without rooting the phone?

Tags: android, kernel

Can Android apps access /dev or /sys without rooting the device?

I have permission problems when doing this from an Activity.
Can it work and the native layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Android apps access /dev or /sys without rooting the device?

AFAIK, no.

> Can it work and the native layer?

If you mean, "can I write an NDK library to access `/dev/` or `/sys/`?", the language in which you write the code will not matter. It is a matter of processes, users, and permissions.

Comment: Yes -- thanks what I mean. Wasn't sure if the permissions come from the Java sandbox, or the kernel's process management. Thank you.